# C++ initializer list & copy constructor

Tags: c++, constructor, initializer-list, default-copy-constructor

I am facing an issue using the {} syntax alongside with the copy constructor.
The following code according to Stroustrup should work (I checked his book and he does this very same example multiple times) but when I try to compile it with gcc it fails (it compiles and works with clang though):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

struct A
{
    int a;
    std::string s;
};

int main()
{
  A a{7, "stefano"};
  A b{a};
  std::cout << "Hello, " << b.s << "!\n";
}
```

The compilation error is:
error: cannot convert 'A' to 'int' in initialization

Clearly it is trying to use the initializer list as list of parameters (therefore trying to assign struct A to int), but according to the language specs it should be possible to call the copy constructor using the {} (and in fact it works in clang).

Is this a peculiarity of gcc? Am I missing something?

Edit: Solution Found:
It seems is a bug in the standard that should be fixed in C++14
(check the "Errata" section here: http://stroustrup.com/4th.html )

Comment: What standard are you compiling against? C++20 this should work, else you need to define the necessary constructor.

Comment: What version of C++ are you compiling your code as?

Comment: You can check which C++ standard you are using:  `std::cout << "C++ version " << __cplusplus << "\n";`